# special characters in HQL

Tags: hql, special-characters

hi i'm trying to get from a mySql DB a query using Hibernates HQL
*

```
public String getDetailsByUserAndFullPath(String user,String fullpath) {
    String temp2 = "%" + user + "%";
            String temp3 = "%" + fullpath + "%";
            // Query query =
            Query query_bd = session
                    .createQuery("from Files files  where user like ? and full_path like ? escape '\'");
            query_bd.setString(0, temp2);
            query_bd.setText(1, temp3);

            List<Files> list = query_bd.list();
```

the problem is the fullpath contains \ such as
c:\temp\example.docx
and i get e query error using the escape
i'm shure it's a small thing but i'm killing myself for two hours already!!
please help
tnx

Answer (score 1):

The `\` is an escape also in your language (that seems to be Java)

so the query looks like this.

```
from Files files  where user like ? and full_path like ? escape ''
```

Try to add another backslash

```
 from Files files  where user like ? and full_path like ? escape '\\'
```

If you are using binded parameter you don't need to escape characters, also i don't recall that this is special character in some DBMS. Also the escape parameter is provided to support more likely the `%` or `_`  characters.

Comment: i'm using java
this did not solve the problem i still get
"org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\')' at line 1"