# How to pass special characters in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, special-characters

I have a query which is working fine using JDBC but when switched to hibernate it throws QueryException for the syntax(`name` is the column in my table `masterTable` using `PostGreSql Database`):

```
String editCodeQuery = "select \"name\" from masterTable";
```

EXCEPTION:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '"' [select "name" from com.lnt.utility.pojo.masterTable
```

Now if i am using the query like this:

```
String editCodeQuery = "select name from masterTable";
```

OR

```
String editCodeQuery = "Select M.name from masterTable M";
```

I get an exception as below(Same error i get if i use the query in JDBC also):

```
    org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
    SEVERE: ERROR: column masterTable0_.name does not exist Position: 8
```

I have to pass special characters in HQL.How do i pass?...Please Help

Comment: You should not surround name with anything, I think. What is the name of the DB column?

Comment: check [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264057/special-characters-in-hql

Comment: Is name a column name or the name of a variable that you need to replace in your method ?

Comment: I have edited my question and added more details...

Answer (score 2):

```
Select M.name from masterTable M
```

The above query is assuming your class is named masterTable(case -sensitive) and name is a property of the class mastertable.

**Keywords like SELECT , FROM and WHERE etc. are not case sensitive but properties like table and column names are case sensitive in HQL.**

Read more about HQL [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You should use your pojo class variable name in select class not a table column name. Map your table column name with pojo by @Column(name="\"name\"").

Comment: @Kanagarj: Yes i have mapped pojo class variable name. Only the issue is how do i pass pojo class variable name escaping the special characters...:(

Comment: Your pojo class variable name won't allow ". Do You want to execute SQL query? mapping will work in HQL only.